# Reset font-size:0 doesn't work with 'em' unit

Tags: css, font-size

I have a *parent* element that sets the `font-size` to 0 (zero) and its *child* that restore the value

```
.parent {
  font-size: 0;
}

.child {
  font-size: 1em;
  /* font-size: 16px; */
}
```

Using `em` it doesn't work. Using `px` as unit makes the text appear again instead.

Can anybody explain me why?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's normal. Because `em` it's a relative meassure. If you think in what are you making, you are making this:

```
0 * 1 = 0
```

So if you reset to 0 you'll obtain forever a zero value.

You need to use `rem` (root em) or `px`.

```
.child {
   font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Rems are from the document